# Typescript confusing error after .js file renamed to .tsx file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, compiler-errors

Sometimes when I try to rename a `.jsx` or `.js` file to `.ts` or `.tsx` I get a really frustrating error in my typescript compilation.

```
TypeScript error in undefined(undefined,undefined):
Type 'never' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.  TS2488
```

I took a long time to figure out that the renaming of the files was the issue. I had this going on for a few times and had to rollback to my latest working commit and merge file by file only to figure out that everything works and the code was exactly the same as the broken code. I have no idea why this happens and starting to suspect it is a bug with typescript.

Today it happened again with a simple react component rename.
this was the component before typescript migration.

```
/* eslint-disable require-jsdoc */
import React from 'react';
import classes from './TableFooter.module.css';
import ButtonPaginateNext from '../Buttons/Pagination/ButtonPaginateNext';
import ButtonPaginateEnd from '../Buttons/Pagination/ButtonPaginateEnd';
import ButtonPaginateBeginning from '../Buttons/Pagination/ButtonPaginateBeginning';
import ButtonPaginatePrevious from '../Buttons/Pagination/ButtonPaginatePrevious';

const TableFooter = ({
  pageNo,
  page,
  handleNext,
  handleBeginning,
  handlePrevious,
  handleEnd,
}) => (
  <div className={classes.FlexWrapper}>
    <div className={classes.FlexItem}>
      {`${page} de ${pageNo}`}
    </div>
    <div className={classes.BtnWrapper}>
      <div className={classes.FlexItem}>
        <ButtonPaginateBeginning />
      </div>
      <div className={classes.FlexItem}>
        <ButtonPaginatePrevious />
      </div>
      <div className={classes.FlexItem}>
        <ButtonPaginateNext />
      </div>
      <div className={classes.FlexItem}>
        <ButtonPaginateEnd />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default TableFooter;
```

I made some small changes and got to this:

```
/* eslint-disable require-jsdoc */
import React from 'react';
import classes from './TableFooter.module.css';
import ButtonPaginateNext from '../Buttons/Pagination/ButtonPaginateNext';
import ButtonPaginateEnd from '../Buttons/Pagination/ButtonPaginateEnd';
import ButtonPaginateBeginning from '../Buttons/Pagination/ButtonPaginateBeginning';
import ButtonPaginatePrevious from '../Buttons/Pagination/ButtonPaginatePrevious';

export interface ITableFooterProps {
  pageNo: number,
  page: number,
  handleNext: () => void,
  handleBeginning: () => void,
  handlePrevious: () => void,
  handleEnd: () => void,
}

const TableFooter: React.FC<Partial<ITableFooterProps>> = ({
  pageNo,
  page,
  handleNext,
  handleBeginning,
  handlePrevious,
  handleEnd,
}) => (
  <div className={classes.FlexWrapper}>
    <div className={classes.FlexItem}>
      {`${page} de ${pageNo}`}
    </div>
    <div className={classes.BtnWrapper}>
      <div className={classes.FlexItem}>
        <ButtonPaginateBeginning />
      </div>
      <div className={classes.FlexItem}>
        <ButtonPaginatePrevious />
      </div>
      <div className={classes.FlexItem}>
        <ButtonPaginateNext />
      </div>
      <div className={classes.FlexItem}>
        <ButtonPaginateEnd />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default TableFooter;
```

After this, everything was working fine even if this typescript compliant code was left as a `.jsx` file. But if I change it to a `.tsx` file. It break with that horrible untreacable error.
What might be the problem.

I'm using the default `tsconfig.json` provided by `create-react-app: ^17.0.2`.

My TS version is `4.1.2`

Comment: The problem might be all you did was change the file extension without changing your code to typescript. You can't just change the filename and the code magically changes languages. Javascript and Typescript are very similar but have important differences. Double check your code when you're using .tsx to make sure you've got the right syntax down.

Comment: So after renaming a file I should add some dummy code (later to be excluded) so typescript can identify it has been changed and re-compile the file entirely? The file is syntactically compliant with typescript.

Comment: Yes. you are correct. I had to change the filename entirely. not just the extension. Re-compile, and the rename the file again to the old name. It actually worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually not. It came back unexpectedly. If I go back to `.jsx` it works again tough. What is the best practice for migration. The documentation states that only extension rename should work.  [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html)

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't migrate your code back and forth. Pick either TS or JS and stick with one. That should help eliminate many of your issues.

Comment: When you say 'it break' you could be explicit about what you did to create the error https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html is a good reference. In my case, when I am working in VSCode and I make changes like this it often gets confused and raises a lot of red underlines and Typescript error notifications which look similar to this, even when the code is fine. When I believe the compiler cache is at fault, with focus in the Typescript file I press CTRL+P (CMD+P on Mac) and then choose Restart TS Server which causes it to fully dump its cache and sort itself out.

Comment: @Kwright02 I'm not. I'm migrating only to TS but having a hard time. Cannot rename files to `.ts`.

Comment: @cefn Thank you for the input. Tried to restart, even re-install TS. It didn't work. I explained exactly what I did to break the code. Renamed a `.js` file to a `.ts` file. Firstly I did it without shutting my server down and later with it shut down. Neither worked

Comment: What I was getting at is that simply renaming it from .js to .ts doesn't mean that your code is now typescript. You still have to follow the TS syntax.

Comment: @Kwright02 Of course. I wrote TS compliant code. Posted this in the issues page in github. If something comes up, I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Renamed the files which I needed to .tsx and changed the code to typescript. Restarted the server. It worked!

Comment: Yeah! This did not work for me. I had to keep a dummy file in my project to make it work. If I delete that file, the error shows up again. I still did not solve this completely. I've tried many things.  Now, I'm always very careful migrating from JS to TS. I always create a new TS file, copy the contents from the JS file, make the changes needed and delete the old JS file. I never rename `.js` to `.ts` anymore.